# How to suppress errors in one specific class in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I write a class in Java and Spring Boot. It is a service, and in the service, it calls other libraries. The problem is when I call the libraries, it will log some errors, these erros actually didn't affect the execution of the service.

So I am wondering, can I suppress the errors in the class?

The service class looks like below.

```
@Service
public class serviceImpl implements service {
    @Override
    public String executeComputation(String rawData, String computationName)
            throws BrokerException, IOException {
    //call some libs
    }
}
```

The error looks like this:

**Unexpected exception during (something) evaluation. Details: Cannot invoke method collectEntries() on null object. Source Code: import java.text.DateFormat;**

Comment: Instead of throwing it you could use a try-catch block, I would assume.

Comment: You said they log errors. So if its just about logging change the logging levels of the class in your spring config (or logger config).

Comment: @TomStroemer Thank you for your suggestion. As the error is from other libraries, and they use logger.error. We have no control of this. But if I use logging level. I should set logging level to fatal to ignore these 'error' message. Am i right?

Comment: @TimHunter Thank you. But the error is from other library that we cannot control. I don't know what should I catch. Like catch(??){}. We can do this for BrokerException, IOException,but we cannot do this for these unknown error, right?

Comment: Most generic catch would be `catch(Exception e){}` but if it's the library itself putting it into a logger instead of throwing it back out for you to handle then I wouldn't know how to handle it beyond digging into the library files or using a configuration the library has (if it had one for that). Not sure how Aniket's answer works, so hopefully that can get you where you want to be with it.

Comment: You can define logging on Package/Class level. So if you really don't care about this errors you can define log-level fatal for only this packages. You can check this article about logging in spring boot: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an aspect for it. An example of aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Around("thePointcutExpression")
    public Object executeComputationAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object ob;      
        try {
            ob = pjp.proceed();
        } catch(Exception e) {} // swallow the exception
        return ob;
    }

}
```